# Default directory of Java 7 on Mountain Lion

Tags: java, macos

Can someone tell me which is the default installation directory for Java 7?

I did follow the above answer and the output of /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7

was

Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.7".
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: Google it and if that doesn't work, ask here on the Apple Stack Exchange: http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:
   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

And don't forget, you may not be seeing it because the LIB folder is hidden.... with every update of OSX So use:

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library/
```

to unhide.

Comment: Its contents are empty. I am thinking I did not download it correctly? I am installing java 7 update 25

Comment: It is still empty after running chflags nohidden ~/Library/

Comment: Possibly not, I have that as well and this is wut I see..../Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk ... but I admit. This is a JDK.

Comment: Re, your question on it being empty after chflags. Before chflags the Lib folder is not visible at all, or any subfolders. After it is, and the contents are either there or not. If you see the Lib folder and no contents, then possibly you DO need to re-install.

Comment: Yup I did something stupid by installing the jre instead of the jdk. Thank you installing jdk 7 worked